# How to schedule spider to run every 5 minutes?

Tags: python, scrapy, scheduled-tasks, scrapy-pipeline

I been trying to figure out how to schedule my scrapy spider for days now without any luck. ( I tried everything from  Windows Task Scheduler to scrapy-do lib but nothing have worked on my **MAIN.PY** )

( my main goal is to schedule my spider to gather data from my spider **NewsSpider** to mySQL **news_db** database every 5 minutes )

Please look at my script as its a bit modified and change it if needed. I really want this to work.

**MAIN.PY**

```
from scrapy import cmdline
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl news".split())
```

**NEWS_SPIDER.PY**

```
import scrapy
from ..items import WebspiderItem


class NewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'news'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.coindesk.com/feed'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        pub_date = response.xpath('//pubDate/text()').extract()[0]
        page_title = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()[2]
        page_summary = response.xpath('//description/text()').extract()[1]
        text_link = response.xpath('//link/text()').extract()[2]

        item = WebspiderItem()
        item['date'] = pub_date
        item['title'] = page_title
        item['summary'] = page_summary
        item['link'] = text_link

        yield item
```

**ITEMS.PY**

```
import scrapy


class WebspiderItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    date = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    summary = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
```

**PIPELINES.PY**

```
import mysql.connector


class WebspiderPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            passwd='passordpassord',
            database='news_db'
        )
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item)
        return item

    def store_db(self, item):
        self.curr.execute("""insert into news_tb values (%s, %s, %s, %s)""", (
            item['date'],
            item['title'],
            item['summary'],
            item['link']

        ))
        self.conn.commit()
```

Comment: Yeah, one nice thing Linux has is cron . . . Windows doesn't have anything similar in the standard WinOS. Task Scheduler exists, but it isn't nearly as flexible.  A little googling found CRONw, but I have no experience with it.  Or you could install a Jenkins instance on your computer.  <wink>

Comment: And of course, on a more serious note, you could just put in your own delay for 5 minutes and start over.

Comment: @FrankMerrow, have you achieved this with Anaconda and cron? I have struggled with this specific conf.

Comment: I assume this is just a hack, so the password really won't be exposed in the final version.  In my own past, I've hidden it as a DOS environment variable and/or just a ROT13 to at least make "shoulder surfing" harder.  There are also some Windows APIs that encrypt to a specific machine, so only somebody with access to your physical machine can decode it.

Answer (score 6):

Using the [schedule package](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) worked for me on both Windows locally and on my Linux server. Simply install it with `pip install schedule`. Then setup a new job by pasting the following into the `main.py` file:

```
import schedule
import time
import os

print('Scheduler initialised')
schedule.every(5).minutes.do(lambda: os.system('scrapy crawl news'))
print('Next job is set to run at: ' + str(schedule.next_run()))

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Then run `python main.py` in the terminal. The script will run the `scrapy crawl news` command every 5 minutes as long as you don't close the terminal.

Please note, that it's quite important to use `os.system()` rather than `cmdline.execute()` since, as far as I recall, `cmdline.execute()` exits the scheduler's infinite while loop when the job is completed. `os.system()` doesn't do this and will therefore wait for another job to run after yet another 5 minutes has passed.